# SSL connection getting closed

Tags: ssl, netty

I have solved the problem. You need to create an instance of SSLEngine and add it to the pipeline of handlers for each clinent request. I have done this by adding the handler in the channelConnected event and removing the ssl handler in the channel disconnected. This make sure for each channel connected it will be added new.

Below is the code of the handler. Is this the right approach for doing persistent socket connection with SSL support?

```
package server;
import static org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.dynamicBuffer;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine;
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffer;
import org.jboss.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.Channel;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelStateEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.ExceptionEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.MessageEvent;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup;
import org.jboss.netty.channel.group.DefaultChannelGroup;
import org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler;
import ssl.SslContextFactory;
import ssl.SslKeyStore;

public class ServerHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {
  private static final String ECHORES   = "0057081082200000000000000400000000000000070612201399966400301";
  @Override
  public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
System.out.println("Inside ServerHandler.messageReceived");
ChannelBuffer buffer = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
ChannelBuffer temp = dynamicBuffer();
temp.writeBytes(buffer);
if (temp.readableBytes() >= 4) {
   byte messageLen[] = new byte[4];
   temp.readBytes(messageLen);
   int len = Integer.parseInt(new String(messageLen));
   System.out.println("Length of the message is : " + len);
   if (temp.readableBytes() >= len) {
       byte[] message = new byte[len];
       temp.readBytes(message);
       System.out.println("Input message is : " + new String(message));
       Channel channel = e.getChannel();
       buffer = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(ECHORES.getBytes());
       ChannelFuture future = channel.write(buffer);
       future.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
   }
}
     }

  @Override
  public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {
e.getCause().printStackTrace();
Channel channel = e.getChannel();
channel.close();
 }

 @Override
 public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
String file = "test.jks";
SSLContext sslCtx = SslContextFactory.getServerContext(new SslKeyStore(file));
final SSLEngine sslEngine =sslCtx.createSSLEngine();
sslEngine.setNeedClientAuth(false);
sslEngine.setUseClientMode(false);
final SslHandler sslHandler = new SslHandler(sslEngine);
ctx.getPipeline().addFirst("ssl", sslHandler);
ChannelFuture handshakeFuture = sslHandler.handshake();
handshakeFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
       if (future.isSuccess()) {
         System.out.println("SSL/TLS session established");
         System.out.println("Your session is protected by "+ sslHandler.getEngine().    
                         getSession().getCipherSuite() + " cipher suite.\n");
       } else {
           future.getChannel().close();
       }
    }
});
    }

    @Override
    public void channelDisconnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
System.out.println("Inside ServerHandler.channelDisconnected");
ctx.getPipeline().remove("ssl");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception while using netty with ssl. My first transaction and handshake goes fine. If I send a new message to teh server again I am getting this exception.

"javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSLEngine is closing/closed"

What could be going wrong here. How to keep the esatablished TLS/SSL session? This error happens at org.jboss.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(SslHandler.java:358).

Intention is to keep the server running with a persistent TLS socket connection , so that clients can send messages.

-TK

Comment: What's your question? Either you have 'solved the problem' or you haven't.

Comment: Solved the problem, trying to get expert advice on whether this is the recommended way to do SSL in netty.

Comment: hi did you solve the problem?... i am connecting using netty and TLS/SSL.. and the connection drops during the handshake..